# Android: How to get SMS from inbox and delete a specific sms

Tags: android, sms

I want to go through all my SMS in Inbox and compare the sender address an the body with a string, and if it's the same, just delete that single sms.

How can I do that?

I just found code to how to delete the whole inbox...

Thanks a lot

James

Answer (score 1):

[Android - Querying the SMS ContentProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584058/android-querying-the-sms-contentprovider)

[Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox)