# How do I watch for SMS for contacts?

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Querying the SMS ContentProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584058/android-querying-the-sms-contentprovider)

Is there a way to watch for SMS (to and from) certain contacts and run methods on the data before the message is sent to the inbox or outbox accordingly?
This would be for android.

Comment: Perhaps you could state the target platform and programming language.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is put a ContentObserver on the sms/inbox table, and then read the Messages from there.

This has been answered **PLENTY** of times. This is the best answer I have seen in a quick look around here.

[Android - Querying the SMS ContentProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584058/android-querying-the-sms-contentprovider)

Please search, at least on here, before you post a question