# Creating Text Messaging App Android

Tags: android, sqlite, text, message

So I am making my own Text Messaging app because I cannot find a decent app out there that can handle Encrypted Messages. So basically what I am doing is making an app that will support AES to encrypt/decrypt messages from other people, and I have a few questions.

1) I realize the phone has to save text messages in a central location, but I can't seem to find it. Where does it save them to?

2) I don't really want a Master Password set-up, but I realize it may be my only option since Obviously a user doesn't want to enter in the password every time, but other than a Master Password I can't think of a secure way to have a phone remember a password. Any ideas?

3) The activity that will actually show all the "Conversations" you are having with contacts, how exactly should it be programmed? I'm guessing that I should use ListActivity, but is there a better/more efficient way out there?

Edit: another question

4) What would be the best way to have a notification in the notification bar at the top? Should I put up a notification inside the SmsReciever?

I think that's all my questions for now, Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There's a load of information on this so long as you know where to look. The sms are [stored in a content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2584058/808940)

2) [Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

3) How exactly is a bit refined for this ... that's your job, but yes list activity is a good place to get you started