# Write sent sms to content://sms/sent table

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am working on an android sms application.I can send sms to single contact by using the following code.

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Now I want to send sms to multicontacts.Some suggest to use loop.SO now I am using loops to send sms to multicontact.

After sending each sms I write those values to sent table.

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", mobNo);
    values.put("body", msg);
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Every new address will create a new thread id.
For example if my receiver's address is x, then thread id 1, for y thread id 2.And if I want to send sms to both x and y ,then how can I write in to sms/sent table.
If I use Loop,then it won't create any new thread id, because send address x already have thread id 1 and y already have thread id 2.So messages will listed under thread id 1 and 2 never creates a new thread id.

I tried to manualy insert thread id by

```
values.put("thread_id", 33);
```

But then the messages under new thread id do not listed in default app but in my app.

Please help me friends

Edit:I tried using 0, and then reading the thread_id that was generated, then place the next sms with this thread_id, still doesn't works.

Comment: so you want a separate combined thread even if there is already a thread for 1 and 2?

Comment: @Nandesh..yes..Native app works like that

Comment: threads are exactly that, they are based on a single number, you cant define a new thread for 2 numbers. You will have to make your own app and have your own db if you want it your way

Comment: native app works like that...They create separate thread id for group conversation

Comment: @nandeesh..I changed my question.Now have a look on this

Comment: @sarath I don't think I can help you with this question, but you could try looking at the source code for the messaging application on github (cyanogenmod or aosp). It helped me once on Android App development.

Comment: @nandeesh actually a new thread is created for grouped contacts, even if each contact may already have another thread for them.

Comment: @vikki...can plz explain a little more with code...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create a new `thread_id` manually, a normal `contentResolver.insert(...)` won't do for multiple recipient messages. To create the new `thread_id` you query the following uri

`content://mms-sms/threadID`

and to it append the necessary recipients so that finally it looks like this

`content://mms-sms/threadID?recipient=9808&recipient=8808`

So the full example would look like this. Say the recipients are `9808` and `8808`

```
Uri threadIdUri = Uri.parse('content://mms-sms/threadID');
Uri.Builder builder = threadIdUri.buildUpon();
String[] recipients = {"9808","8808"};
for(String recipient : recipients){
    builder.appendQueryParameter("recipient", recipient);
}
Uri uri = builder.build();
```

Now you can query `uri` in the normal way and this will give you a `thread_id` that you can use for the recipients specified, it will create a new id if one doesn't exist or return an existing one.

```
Long threadId = 0;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{"_id"}, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            threadId = cursor.getLong(0);
            }
    } finally {
            cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Now use `threadId` to insert your SMSs.

A few things to note.

Do not use this `threadId` to insert single recipient messages for either `9908` or `8808`, create a new thread_id for each or just do an `insert` without specifying the `thread_id`.

Also, be very careful with the `builder.appendQueryParameter(...)` part, make sure the key is `recipient` and not `recipients`, if you use `recipients` it will still work but you will always get the same `thread_id` and all your SMSs will end up in one thread.

Comment: @vikki..Thank u...let me check

Comment: @vikki....for all conversations it creates only one thread id..my key is recipient only...my code snippet is  String[] recipients = to_nums.toArray(new String[to_nums.size()]);;
        for(String recipient : recipients){
            builder.appendQueryParameter("recipient", recipient);
        }

Comment: I don't think you're using toArray properly, if to_nums is an array of strings then just iterate over that you don't need to convert it into a String[],

Comment: @Vikki..Have a look on this question pls..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577036/broadcast-receiver-stops-when-i-click-back-button

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should create a new thread for the group message and insert it into the new thread as well as the individual threads.

Comment: Hi..I tried to put new thread id by values.put("thread_id", 33);..After that I can list the group conversation but the default sms app is not listing the conversation with new threadid.

Comment: Did you create the new thread using content resolver insert and assign its Id in the message?

Comment: The following code i used to inset group sms..ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", mobNo);
    values.put("body", msg);values.put("thread_id", 33);
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);

Comment: Yes, however a thread row should be inserted separately and it's id retrieved and inserted as the thread Id. You should have two inserts.

Comment: Hi i did separately .And I can view the new conversation.But the default sms app not showing  the conversation..ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("address", phoneNumber);
     values.put("body", message);
     values.put("thread_id", 99);

     getContentResolver().insert(
       Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);. Twice i did

Comment: Take a look at this, has more info on working with SMS uris. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584058/android-querying-the-sms-contentprovider

Comment: Ya..actually I used those links when I start my application..But for insert multi messgae for multicontacts i didnot get