# How to update sms thread after inserting a draft in "content://sms/draft"

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I am using the following code to insert a draft into content://sms/draft

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", receiver2);
        values.put("body", body2);
        values.put("date", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        values.put("type", "3");
        values.put("thread_id", thread_id);
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/draft"), values);
```

thread_id is 0 if there wasn't any conversation with the address above, else it's the id of that thread.

When I run this code, the draft is indeed saved, but thread in the native sms client (stock android 4.0.3) isn't updated as "draft" [I can see the draft message body, but there is no "Draft" label on it. I have to open-close the thread, in order to be marked as marked]. I have read somewhere that there is an issue with the thread not updating properly. How can I force the threads to be updated so it shows ok in all the clients?

**EDIT:**

Having read your answers, I have updated my code a bit, but the problem remains. I have added a screenshot below, since when I wrote my question I was in a hurry and couldn't write it clearly enough.

```
protected void save_draft(String[] recipients, String body) {
        Uri threadIdUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/threadID");
        Uri.Builder builder = threadIdUri.buildUpon();
        for (String recipient : recipients) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter("recipient", recipient);
        }
        Uri uri = builder.build();
        Long thread_id = get_thread_id(uri);
        Log.d("thread_id", thread_id + " ");

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("body", body);
        values.put("date", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        values.put("type", 3);
        values.put("thread_id", thread_id);
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/draft"), values);
        //^tried "content://sms/" as well, but got the same result
    }

    private Long get_thread_id(Uri uri) {
        long threadId = 0;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { "_id" },
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    threadId = cursor.getLong(0);
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return threadId;
    }
```

[image: a busy cat]

As you can see, there is no "Draft" label, next to the draft I made via the code above.

Comment: In messaging app, Open the draft and close it again. See if draft label appears or not. This is because certain SQLite triggers are required to run to auto complete the values you didn't provide.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, the draft label *does* appear after I open-close a thread. Is there any way to fire that trigger via my app?

Comment: If you kill messaging app and restart it, It shows every thing correctly. This is a problem will messaging app. So, I'm not sure what can be done about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I made this question, but here is the answer:

First of all as stated before, the fact that the "Draft" hint doesn't appear on the Native SMS app, shouldn't be bothering anyone. Nothing can be done about it, and it's just the way the Native SMS app works. In particular a cache is initialised when the app starts, saving the thread ids of the  threads that contain a draft. The draft cache is updated only from the app itself and not from an actual change in the sms table

For the saving draft part here is the piece of code to save a draft properly:

```
   public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");

   public static Uri addDraft(ContentResolver resolver,
            String address, String body, String subject,
            Long date,  long threadId) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(6);

        values.put(ADDRESS, address);
        if (date != null) {
            values.put(DATE, date);
        }
        values.put(READ, Integer.valueOf(1));
        values.put(SUBJECT, subject);
        values.put(BODY, body);
        if (threadId != -1L) {
            values.put(THREAD_ID, threadId);
        }
        return resolver.insert(CONTENT_URI , values);
    }
```

Note: Draft messages may or may not contain the address of the recipient of the message. Drafts are saved on the *thread* (a thread can contain many recipients)

Although the sms database is not documented  at all, you can grab the Telephony class from the AOSP and have a look at how to add/remove messages and handle various tasks about sms and mms.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/provider/Telephony.java

Comment: will this update the draft if any ? if not how get the previous draft and update

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach is different from built-in messaging application.

> thread_id is 0 if there wasn't any conversation with the address above, else it's the id of that thread.

As far as i know even draft got auto generated `thread_id`. If it's not, all draft (had receiver address never appeared) will group at the same conversation with `thread_id` = 0

Here is how built-in app add an draft.

```
 public static final Uri SmsCONTENT_URI =
            Uri.parse("content://sms");
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        values.put("thread_id", threadId);
        values.put("body", contents); // 
        values.put("type", Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT); // type = 3 is draft.
        SqliteWrapper.insert(mActivity, mContentResolver, Sms.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Final reminder : This is not `public API` to access message data so I don't suggest you to use. But now is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, since it made me look up some things about the hidden part of the api. Afaik if you write thread_id = 0, it will generate a unique thread_id, at least in my code it does.
I have updated my question a bit with a screenshot and updated code. No new result yet.

Comment: Actual thread_Id is an auto Increment Integer, hence its not always 0. Also, when you query `content://mms-sms/ThreadId` with recipient addresses as parameters, Either an already existing thread_Id (if address combination matches `recipient_Ids`) or a new thread_Id is returned. Why this is needed because, in sms table `address` field is null for drafts.

Answer (score 2):

Use the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12243870/1531054) , just insert to `content://sms/draft` instead of `content://sms/sent`.

Comment: I tried updating my code accordingly to that answer, but the outcome remains the same :/

Check the edit if you please

Answer (score 2):

thanks a lot i have try `save_draft()` try this and insert into `inbox/sent/draft` etc....

```
public class AddData {

Activity act;
Context ctx,context;
ContentResolver cr;

public AddData(Activity act)
{

    cr = act.getContentResolver();
    this.act = act;
}
public void addsms(String address,String body,String date,String type,String read)
{
    String[] addr = address.split(" ");
    String thread_id = save_draft(addr);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("body", body);
     values.put("date", date);
     values.put("type", type);
     if(type.equals("3"))
     {
         values.put("thread_id", thread_id); 
     }else
     {
         values.put("address", address);
     }

     Uri uri = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), values);
     cr.notifyChange(uri, null);

}

 protected String save_draft(String[] recipients) {
     Uri threadIdUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/threadID");
     Uri.Builder builder = threadIdUri.buildUpon();
     for (String recipient : recipients) {
         builder.appendQueryParameter("recipient", recipient);
     }
     Uri uri = builder.build();
     String thread_id = get_thread_id(uri).toString();
     Log.d("thread_id", thread_id + " ");


     //^tried "content://sms/" as well, but got the same result
     return thread_id;
 }

 private Long get_thread_id(Uri uri) {
     long threadId = 0;
     Cursor cursor = act.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { "_id" },
             null, null, null);
     if (cursor != null) {
         try {
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 threadId = cursor.getLong(0);
             }
         } finally {
             cursor.close();
         }
     }
     return threadId;
 }
```

}