# Receving binary SMS on port also stores a copy of SMS in inbox

Tags: android, binary, sms

I am developing a banking application. We have a binary SMS functionality where the application listens to a specific port for SMS. The application is able to receive SMS but a copy of SMS is also stored in inbox. I do not want the SMS to be stored in inbox. It must be receid only by the application. Can you please help me on how to overcome this issue?

regards,
Chinnadurai

Comment: Which device is this on? I believe by default, this shouldn't happen (but does on some devices, e.g. Samsung Galaxy).

Comment: I tested it on Sonyericsson Xperia x10i

Answer (score 0):

you can set priority to your broadcast recevier like this
if your are registering receiver in code
filter.setPriority(10);
otherwise like this  in manifest

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that this is possible using SMS. Your option is to delete the SMS as soon as possible. How to do that has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183680/delete-sms-in-android-1-5).

Comment: I haven't tried it for binary SMS, but this may be a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox/2566199#2566199

Comment: Is it possible to delete the SMS from inbox even before the user is notified about new message? My solution need is that the user should not be notified that there is a new SMS. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: chinnadurai: I don't think so.

Comment: I have now tested the approach I mentioned in my first comment and it does work. Using that, the SMS will never appear in the user's inbox, so there is no need to delete it.