# Count outgoing SMS / MMS in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

I am creating a project where I have to periodically check the number of sent SMS and MMS in that timer period. For example, number of sent SMS/MMS in last 15 minutes.

I have seen this [post: How to use SMS content provider? Where are the docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976557/777593) and Mark Murphy (CommonsWare) has mentioned not to use the SMS content provider because it is un-documented.

In the light of above, what can I do to achieve my goal?

@CommonsWare Can you please comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [a refactored version of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183680/delete-sms-in-android-1-5#2198104) to get what you need, I think.

SAMPLE:

```
private int deleteMessage(Context context, SmsMessage msg) {
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
int count = 0;
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(deleteUri, null, null,
        null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
    try {
        // Delete the SMS
        String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
        String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
        count = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(uri),
                null, 
                "date('sentDate') - date('%M', '15') > date('now')", 
                null, 
                null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
return count;
```

}

The SQL might be completely wrong, but something like this should work.

Comment: Yes, I may be able to use sms content provider to read sms data. But referring to my question, I would prefer not to use sms content-provider as it is undocumented as indicated by Mark Murphy.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the only way to do so.