# Need help to delete single SMS Android app Java

Tags: java, android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete SMS in Android 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183680/delete-sms-in-android-1-5)

I have searched the internet for some days now, but can't find any similar problems.

I am making an Android app, and I would like to delete a single SMS, not the whole conversation.

When the phone recives an SMS, I save the timestamp and when I am going to delete the message, I find the timestamp.  But I can only delete the whole thread, not the single SMS, help please?

```
            String pid = c.getString(1);
            String uri = "content://sms/conversations/" + pid;
            //Log.i(rm,"0 "+ c.getString(5) + " " +AllSmsTime.toString());
            //Log.i(rm ,"2 " + c.getLong(1));
            if(Long.valueOf(c.getString(5)).longValue()== AllSmsTime.get(0)){
                /*gets milliseconds*/

                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);    
            }
```

Comment: The accepted answer in the above question will probably work for you.